# Determine whether the following sequences converge or diverge. Prove your findings. $a_n = n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Well obviously when n approaches infinity its infinity. It diverges. How would I go about proving this?

Can I do this by contradition?

WTS: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $\left| n - \infty \right| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon = 1$

if $n > N$, then $n = \infty$ Yeah i don't know.

Comment: This doesn't work, $n-\infty$ is not defined. (And where's the contradiction in your solution ?)

Comment: You need to revise the definition of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$. It is not the same as the usual epsilon-delta definition for finite limits.

Comment: However, to prove that it diverges, you don't actually need to show that it goes to infinity.

Comment: @DHMO: I don't see anything wrong in the definition, which is not an $\epsilon/\delta$. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Infinity is not a number. The two instances of $\infty$ that you see in $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$ do not actually mean infinity.

Comment: @DHMO: this does not invalidate the definition of convergence.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm talking about the definition of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$.

Comment: What you are saying is, I should have kept it as L so $|n - L| < \epsilon$ ? Anyways I have no idea how to prove divergence for sequences if its not alternating. Any suggestions? My notes don't have anything on it.

Comment: @DHMO: how would you define that ?

Comment: I think this definition would quantify what $n\to\infty$ means but it's not in any textbook: $n\to\infty$ means that for any given value $N\in \mathbb{N},$ we can always find $n > N$. Proof: choose $n = N+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, for the sake of a contradiction, that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$.

That is, $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists n_0 \in \Bbb N: \forall n > n_0: |a_n-L| < \epsilon$.

By the [Archimedean Principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle), there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N>L$.

Now, let $\epsilon = 1$. If $n_0 > N$, then take $n=n_0+1$. $|a_n-L| = |n_0+1-L| = n_0-L+1 \ge 1$, a contradiction.

If $n_0 < N$, then take $n = N+1$. $|a_n-L| = |N+1-L| = N-L+1 \ge 1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**By contradiction**:

Let the limit be $L$. By definition $L$ is such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, $\forall$ $n > N$, $\left| n - L \right| < \epsilon$.

But

$$-\epsilon<n-L<\epsilon$$

implies 
$$\epsilon<n+2\epsilon-L
$$

so that for all $n>N+2\epsilon> N$,

$$|n-L|>\epsilon,$$ a contradiction.